# Flutter - Make custom text editing controller

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I want to make a custom text editing controller which will show the numbers of text in Farsi (Persian), but returns it with English numbers when you call `textEditingController.text`.

Here's what I have implemented but it seems like the TextField doesn't use the setter of `text`:

```
class PersianTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {

  @override
  String get text => value.text.toEnglishNumbers;

  @override
  set text(String newText) {
    value = value.copyWith(
      text: newText.toPersianNumbers,
      selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: -1),
      composing: TextRange.empty,
    );
  }

  factory PersianTextEditingController({String? text}) =>
      PersianTextEditingController._(text: text);

  PersianTextEditingController._({String? text}) {
    this.text = text ?? '';
  }

}
```

Here's the TextField:

```
PersianTextEditingController controller = PersianTextEditingController();
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextField(
          controller: widget.controller,
        );
      }
```

Comment: could you include toEnglishNumbers and toPersianNumbers too?

Comment: Instead of creating a new class. Just create an extension on TextEditingController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you try to get english number with getter `text`, inside the `TextEditingController` its use it, so always you are getting english number, you need to set `text` to `farsi` and define new `getter` for english number, like this:

```
class PersianTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  String get text => value.text.toPersianNumbers;

  String get englishText => value.text.toEnglishNumbers;

  factory PersianTextEditingController({String? text}) =>
      PersianTextEditingController._(text: text);

  PersianTextEditingController._({String? text}) {
    this.text = text ?? '';
  }
}
```

but when you want to get your english number use this:

```
print("text = ${widget.controller.englishText}")
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
   class PersianTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  String get text => super.value.text.toPersianNumbers;

  @override
  set text(String persianText) {
    super.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: persianText.toEnglishNumbers,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: persianText.length),
    );
  }
}
```

and:

```
TextField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: (value) {
        print(controller.text);
    
      },
    ),
```

Comment: This is working while typing, but I also wanted to get the English numbers using `controller.text` but seems like it's not possible. right?

Comment: I don't follow, you want that controller.text will return numbers in English and in Persian ? can you clear what exactly you want

Comment: I want `controller.text` to return numbers in English but show the text in `TextField` in Persian.

Comment: of so the reverse of languages in your case, change your toPersianNumbers to toEnglishNumbers and vice versa !